# Quick look for KDE?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, macosx, dolphin

As per title, I'm searching if there is something similar to OSX's Quick Look or Gnome's Gloobus Preview for KDE: searching Google brought me to some KDE's brainstorms, but nothing more.

Also to [Duong Pham](http://dthpham.com/post/21425848691/gloobus-preview-in-kde) website, where he suggest to add a Dolphin sevice menu item installing Gloobus Preview and then create the .desktop file: this is not a solution, because you have to right click and select "preview", rather than just press <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

Any idea?

Answer (score 9):

**Preview KDE**

Dolphin > Settings > Configure Dolphin > General > Previews.

[image]

To preview the KDE need the thumbnailer to be installed:

Few examples:

- kde-thumbnailer-audiothumbs
- kdegraphics-thumbnailers
- kde-thumbnailer-openoffice
- ffmpegthumbs

Dolphin > View > Panels > information (F11)

The Information panel will show the preview and the information of the object.

[image]

Dolphin > Settings > Configure Dolphin > General > Show tooltips

The tooltip will show the the preview and the information of the object.

[image]

The preview plasma widget will show the preview when the image is dropped on the widget.

[image]

**More**

Missing image dimensions in dolphin: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?58122-No-image-dimensions-in-dolphin

**KLook**

The KDE 4.9 /1/ could have the KLook /2/,/3/. It is something like the Gloobus /4/ but for the KDE.

The KLook is working with the KDE 4.8 /5/.

**Advanced preview**

There are ways to get auto preview with the KDE file managers /6, 7/ but they are using modified/patched Dolphin/Konqueror.

**Links**

1. http://techbase.kde.org/Schedules/KDE4/4.9_Feature_Plan
2. http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/04/09/klook-a-swiss-army-knife-of-media-type-viewers/
3. http://www.koryavov.net/2012/03/klook-new-utility-for-kde-and-rosa.html
4. http://gloobus.net/gloobus-preview/
5. http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?59000-KLook-with-the-KDE-4-8-Kubuntu-12-04
6. https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?63185-Auto-preview-audio-and-video-files-in-the-Dolphin-and-Konqueror
7. https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?64974-audio-video-preview-integrated-in-dolphin

Comment: You can rename yourself at your profile. userSOMENUMBER doesn't look that nice ;)